# For loop only reads first term of array

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

```
def CFW(D):
    for a in WL:
        if D == 0:
```

CFW is a function that returns if the player is touching a wall (D is for the direction)
WL is an array that contains arrays of coordinates of walls, however it will only read the first array in WL, and not iterate to the next, so it will only return if the player is touching the first set of coordinates in WL. can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
here is the entire function:

```
def CFW(D):
    for a in WL:
        if D == 0:
            if a[0] > (plyposx-30) and a[0] < (plyposx+30) and plyposy == a[1]-32:
                return 1 # 1 = is touching
            else:
                return 0 # 0 = is not touching
        elif D == 2:
            if a[0] > (plyposx-30) and a[0] < (plyposx+30) and plyposy == a[1]+32:
                return 1
            else:
                return 0
        elif D == 1:
            if a[1] > (plyposy-30) and a[1] < (plyposy+30) and plyposx == a[0]+32:
                return 1
            else:
                return 0
        elif D == 3:
            if a[1] > (plyposy-30) and a[1] < (plyposy+30) and plyposx == a[0]-32:
                return 1
            else:
                return 0
```

I changed the code to

```
def CFW(D):
    for c in xrange(0,1):
    a = WL[c]
        if D == 0:
```

However it still does not read the second array.
the way I have defined  WL is like this:

```
WL = [[32,32],[64,32]]
```

Comment: What does `WL` look like?

Comment: WL = [[32,32],[64,32]]

Comment: Assuming D always equals either 0, 1, 2, or 3 every code path in your for loop returns.

Comment: They do, however my problem is that it only returns for one set of coordanates

Answer (score 2):

At a first glance, I thought this was what you wanted to do:

```
def CFW(D):
  for a in WL:
    if D == 0:
      if a[0] > (plyposx-30) and a[0] < (plyposx+30) and plyposy == a[1]-32:
        return 1 # 1 = is touching
    elif D == 2:
      if a[0] > (plyposx-30) and a[0] < (plyposx+30) and plyposy == a[1]+32:
        return 1
    elif D == 1:
      if a[1] > (plyposy-30) and a[1] < (plyposy+30) and plyposx == a[0]+32:
        return 1
    elif D == 3:
      if a[1] > (plyposy-30) and a[1] < (plyposy+30) and plyposx == a[0]-32:
        return 1
  return 0 # 0 = is not touching
```

It is worth noting that `range` and `xrange` classes support the `in` operation:

```
>>> 5 in xrange(1, 10)
True
>>> 100 in xrange(1, 10)
False
```